# error using label and regionprops in skimage,<sz = footprint.shape[ii] IndexError: tuple index out of range>

Tags: python, image, label, rgb, scikit-image

I work on python 2.7.

I want to label picture, so I use skimage, skimage.label and skimage.regionprops packages.

I've found a great code on scikit-image.org :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches

from skimage import data
from skimage.filters import threshold_otsu
from skimage.segmentation import clear_border
from skimage.measure import label, regionprops
from skimage.morphology import closing, square
from skimage.color import label2rgb


image = data.coins()[50:-50, 50:-50]

# apply threshold
thresh = threshold_otsu(image)
bw = closing(image > thresh, square(3))

# remove artifacts connected to image border
cleared = clear_border(bw)

# label image regions
label_image = label(cleared)
image_label_overlay = label2rgb(label_image, image=image)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 6))
ax.imshow(image_label_overlay)

for region in regionprops(label_image):
    # take regions with large enough areas
    if region.area >= 100:
        # draw rectangle around segmented coins
        minr, minc, maxr, maxc = region.bbox
        rect = mpatches.Rectangle((minc, minr), maxc - minc, maxr - minr,
                                  fill=False, edgecolor='red', linewidth=2)
        ax.add_patch(rect)

ax.set_axis_off()
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

The problem is, when I put my png rgb picture, it doesn't work and more preciesly I got this error message :

```
sz = footprint.shape[ii]  IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

I've also noticed that `data.coins().shape = (303L, 384L)` which is not a rgb picture. How come?

Comment: This code looks like it was designed to run on a gray image.  You can convert your color image to gray using `skimage.color.rgb2gray`.

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much!